# Python loop add up a float, the result is not right

Tags: python

I was using a simple for loop to add numbers but I found a strange result when adding float.

Can you explain why I have the following output ?

```
1.1
1.2000000000000002
1.3000000000000003
1.4000000000000004
1.5000000000000004
1.6000000000000005
1.7000000000000006
1.8000000000000007
1.9000000000000008
2.000000000000001
2.100000000000001
2.200000000000001
2.300000000000001
2.4000000000000012
2.5000000000000013
2.6000000000000014
2.7000000000000015
2.8000000000000016
2.9000000000000017
3.0000000000000018
3.100000000000002
3.200000000000002
3.300000000000002
3.400000000000002
3.500000000000002
3.6000000000000023
3.7000000000000024
3.8000000000000025
3.9000000000000026
```

This is based on Anaconda Spyder

```
a = 1

for i in range(1,30):
    a = a+0.1
    print(a)
```

Comment: This is well known and due to the way the floats are stored

Answer (score 1):

It's a known limitation of floating point arithmetic, computers cannot store infinitely precise floating point numbers. See [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).